# How to use expansion_optr found in help macro?

Tags: stata

In the stata `help macro` page near the bottom is says `where expansion_optr is` and lists the following:

- *++lclname*
- *lclname++*
- *--lclname*
- *=exp*
- *:extended_fnm*
- *.class_directive*
- *macval(lclname)*

Is anyone aware of any documentation (beyond what is found in the `macro` help file) that gives some examples of how to use these operations? If no good documentation can be found, any examples using macros with `expansion_optr` would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you studied the extensive Remarks and Examples section [in the manual](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/pmacro.pdf)? You can access this same entry by clicking on the blue `[P] macro` link at the top of the help file.

Here are some examples to play with:

```
local i=0
local j=0
while `i'<= 1 {
    di "Increment i=`i' immediately to get `++i'"
    di "    i is now `i'"
    di "j=`j' plus 1 will be (`j++'+1) next time"
    di "    j is currently `j'"
}

sysuse auto, clear
des price
local label: variable label price
di as red "price's label is `label'"
```

which gets you:

[image]